# Is it possible to take out more tokens than what's in a reserve?

Tags: bsc, decentralized-exchange, pancakeswap, binance, liquidity-provider

My understanding was that one cannot transact more than what is available in a liquidity pool.

However, this transaction seems to prove me wrong:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xdd38b435d9840062db9106e23712873fa2da44c366fa737b17f7fc6d111ef076#eventlog

Here, `1000000000000000000` worth of BUSD was traded for `172054109197`.

However, prior to this trade, the [last `Sync` event](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x42768a852f06899d26b578f3a3cc100332d97dca5ec2381a31a115eb5daf2a32#eventlog) describes the following [Zombie / BUSD LP](https://bscscan.com/address/0xde7c6452072a4bd77a6633969bdf579f8644f111) balance:

```
reserve0: 1203765031
reserve1: 6402195517789394391
```

How is it possible that `172054109197` Zombie tokens were bought if LP had less than that tokens?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

The reserve must be greater than the amount out of that reserve. This is enforced by this line of code in the pair contract:

```
require(amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1, 'Pancake: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
```

I did not study the transaction that you posted, but you can be sure that the reserve of zombie tokens in the pancake pair was greater than the amount transferred out at the time the swap was made.